# How to redirect traffic sent to tap to a specific ip addr

Tags: iptables, routing, socket, redirection, tap

I created a tap device using the following commands:

```
sudo ip tuntap add mode tap tap7
sudo ip link set tap7 up
sudo ip addr add 77.0.0.1/24 dev tap7
```

Now, I am using c++ sockets programming to write packets to `tap7` and I am able to capture them with wireshark when it listens to `tap7` interface.
What I need is to create a rule that any packet written to `tap7` should be redirected to the ip `127.0.0.1`.

I tried the following commands:

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i tap7 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i tap7 -j ACCEPT
```

However, when I listen on wireshark, I still see that packets are captured on `tap7` and not captured from `lo` device. Does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the `route_localnet` sysctl option for the `tap7` interface. You should be able to accomplish this with the `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.tap7.route_localnet=1` command, depending on your distro.

```
route_localnet - BOOLEAN
    Do not consider loopback addresses as martian source or destination
    while routing. This enables the use of 127/8 for local routing purposes.
    default FALSE
```

More (brief) information on the security implications of `route_localnet` can be found in [this thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/137602/what-are-the-security-implications-of-net-ipv4-conf-eth0-route-localnet-1-rout)

Hope this helps

Comment: The same problem happens even if I change `127.0.0.1` to a different ip. Which means that the problem is not only because of using `lo`

Comment: Ah, in that case you also need to run `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` to enable IP forwarding in the kernel

Comment: I already did that, but it seems that you misunderstand me. I have a packet with source ip `s` and destination ip `d`. Now regardless of `d`, I write this packet to `tap7` which has a third ip `t`. what you mentioned works if and only if `d` = `t` (which is not my case)

Comment: If the source packets are not destined for the `tap7` IP address, then this can never work as an `ESTABLISHED` TCP connection, since `s` only knows that `d` receives the packet and not `t`.

However, your `tcpdump` should still be able to see the packet hit the `lo` interface

Comment: So why I am not able to see that on wireshark ?

Comment: At this point, the wireshark should at least be working.

Try this instead, which will enable `route_localnet` for all interfaces (just in case we are missing something):

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1`

Comment: If my most recent comment doesn't solve the issue, then instead of using `DNAT` try using `REDIRECT` without any additional arguments. Info on `REDIRECT` found here: https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/x4529.html